# Pass this.props.children to another file in react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I try to render a React Component in my page using react-router.

The file structure I use is the one bellow:

```
React/
  components/
    Container/
      Sidebar.js
      Main.js
    Container.js
    Header.js
    Layout.js
  pages/
    Main.js
    Lesson.js
  index.js
```

So I want to render the components from the `pages` folder in the component that belongs to `Main.js`. The `Sidebar.js` holds the navigation menu.

Here is what I tried:

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';

import Layout from './components/Layout';

import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory } from 'react-router';

import Index from './pages/Index';
import Lesson from './pages/Lesson';

const app = document.getElementById('app');
ReactDom.render(
  <Router history={hashHistory} >
    <Route path="/" component={Layout} >
      <IndexRoute component={Index} ></IndexRoute>
      <Route path="lesson" name="lesson" component={Lesson} ></Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>
,app);
```

**Layout.js**

```
import React from 'react';

import Header from './Header';
import Container from './Container';

export default class Layout extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Container />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Container.js**

```
import React from 'react';

import Sidebar from './Container/Sidebar';
import Main from './Container/Main';

export default class Header extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="container">
        <Sidebar />
        <Main />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Main.js**

import React from 'react';

export default class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      
        
         {/* Here I want to render the contents */}
        
      
    );
  }
}

**Sidebar.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import sidebarStore from './Sidebar/SidebarStore.js';


export default class Sidebar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="nav-md-placeholder">
        <nav id="sidebar">
          <ul id="main-menu">
            <li class="ripple-btn">
              <Link to="/">
                <span class="item-align-fix">
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" style={{'marginRight': '10px'}}></i>
                  <strong>
                    <span>index</span>
                  </strong>
                </span>
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li class="ripple-btn">
              <Link to="lesson">
                <span class="item-align-fix">
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" style={{'marginRight': '10px'}}></i>
                  <strong>
                    <span>lesson</span>
                  </strong>
                </span>
              </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I don't get any errors on my console when building the app nor in th browser console. When I click on the links I redirect to the following urls but nothing happen:

```
Click on Index -> http://localhost/new-webclass/#/?_k=gukonu
Click on Lesson -> http://localhost/new-webclass/#/lesson?_k=7mcbcx
```

I don't know if I setted the routes with the wrong way. The official documentation doesn't help either.

Here is also the example of the **Lesson.js** I want to render:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Lesson extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Lesson Page</h1>
    );
  }
}
```

### Solution

See the answer of **Random User** bellow. He provides a nice explanation. So down bellow you see how I passed `{this.props.children}` to the file with the component I needed:

**Layout.js**

```
<Container main_content={this.props.children}/>
```

**Container.js**

```
<Main main_content={this.props.main_content}/>
```

**Main.js**

```
render() {
    return (
      <main class={this.MainContentPlaceholder} id="main-content-placeholder">
        <Overlay />
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 center-col">
        {this.props.main_content}
        </div>
      </main>
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `index.js` file

```
<Router history={hashHistory} >
  <Route path="/" component={Layout} >
    <IndexRoute component={Index} ></IndexRoute>
    <Route path="lesson" name="lesson" component={Lesson} ></Route>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

`<Route path="/" component={Layout} >` acts as the parent route and all other routes are its `sub-routes`. and its using **`Layout`** component

So even when you change the route, the `parent component` remains there and the component of new route is passed to the parent component `Layout` as a `children`, but you're not rendering children in your `Layout` component.

So, in your `Layout.js` file, add this line **`{this.props.children}`**, Example

```
return (
  <div>
    <Header />
    <Container />
    {this.props.children}
  </div>
);
```

You can Re-arrange it to suit your needs, but add **`{this.props.children}`** wherever you want to render the child components passed to it.

---

### Edit

I think you're complicating things, Anyways you could do this

In `Layout.js`, You can pass the children to your container like

```
<Container>
  {this.props.children}
</Container>
```

And in `Container.js` pass the children using same technique

```
<Main>
  {this.props.children}
</Main>
```

And in `Main.js`

```
render() {
    return (
      <main className={this.MainContentPlaceholder} id="main-content-placeholder">
        <Overlay />
        <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 center-col">
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </main>
    );
```

Remember to use **className** prop instead of using **class**, In `React JSX` if you want to set `class` on an `element` you have to use `className` prop instead of `class` prop

---

**Note:** I think it would be best if you can place all the visual elements in your layout file, like `Header`, `Navigation`, `Sidebar`, `Footer` and then place `this.props.children` in a `wrapper div`, So the content within the wrapper will keep changing as you navigate between different routes., And you can update the header, navigation, aside, etc **data**, **active states** using your **store**.

Comment: I wanted to pass the children prop to the file I had the main component. I updated the question with an answer that works. I just want to be sure that this is the correct way to do it. Please review it and tell me. Thank you very match!

Comment: @GeorgeGkas updated the answer., I think it would be best if you can simplify your `Layout` and keep things more simple.. but depending on what you're working on.. it might not be possible.

Comment: I don't know what will be the size of the project. It's the first time I use react. I  over-abstract things just in case. :) Also I use babel-plugin-react-html-attrs to get rid the className.

Comment: Ok, as long as its working for you.., over abstraction is not a bad thing., Didn't knew about `babel-plugin-react-html-attrs`